# get wrong size from 2d vector pointer in c++

Tags: c++, stdvector

I create a 2d vector, however when I read the size from this 2d vector pointer, it gets wrong size. I have no idea about, can anyone explain this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

void read_size(std::vector<std::vector<float>> *vec)
{
    printf("read size %d, %d\n", vec->size(), vec[0].size());
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> vec;
    vec.resize(100);
    vec[0].resize(50);
    printf("main %d, %d\n", vec.size(), vec[0].size());
    read_size(&vec);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
main 100, 50
read size 100, 100
```

I think both size should be 100, 50

Comment: Useless use of pointer : `std::vector<std::vector<float>> *vec` -> ` const std::vector<std::vector<float>&`. Also note resize will not add elements to the vector.

Comment: In `read_size`, `vec[0].size()` should be `(*vec)[0].size()`  (if you insist to use a pointer).

Comment: A few things: First of all the `size` function returns a value compatible with `size_t` (probably an alias for `size_t`) and the proper `printf` format for `size_t` values is `%zu`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*. And related to that, why are you using `printf`? As you demonstrate, it's not type-safe. Why don't you use the standard C++ streams like `std::cout`? Which will handle it all perfectly well. Then don't pass a pointer to the vector, pass a (`const`) *reference*. Which, as demonstrated, will solve your problem.

Comment: There's no need for a pointer, pass the vector by reference. All passing a pointer did was make your code harder to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vec->size()` is equiavlent to `(*vec).size()`.

`vec[0]` is equivalent to `*(vec + 0)`, which is equivalent to `*vec`.

Therefore, `vec->size()` and `vec[0].size()` are the same things.

You should first dereference the pointer `vec` in the function `read_size` to access to its elements.

This can be done like `(*vec)[0].size()`, `vec[0][0].size()`, or `vec->at(0).size()`.

Answer (score 0):

In this statement:

```
printf("read size %d, %d\n", vec->size(), vec[0].size());
```

the expressions `vec->size()` and `vec[0].size()` are equivalent. Instead of the expression `vec[0].size()` you should use the expression `vec[0[0].size()`.

Pay attention to that this call of printf:

```
printf("read size %d, %d\n", vec->size(), vec[0].size());
```

in any case in general has undefined behavior because the return type of the member function size() is an unsigned integer type usually equivalent to the type size_t.

You should write instead:

```
std::cout << "read size " <<  vec->size() << ", " << vec[0][0].size() <<  '\n';
```